# Responsive Javascript Image Resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Apologies for the general question but I have been looking to implement an image showcase similar to the new Flickr layout like in this [example](http://www.flickr.com/photos/51807315@N04/with/8758268569/)

The difficulty I am having is in the responsive design. I have looked at various plugins including: Isotope, Wookmark, Grid-a-licious but all of these solutions either leave uneven margins/gutters when the browser window is resized or don't align at the bottom in the style of pinterest where things are just stacked vertically on rows.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a plugin that would resize images to completely fill the width of rows and align all images correctly at the bottom like on Flickr.

Alternatively it would be great to know where to get started on the javascript for something like this?

Comment: Have you looked at [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have indeed but found that it was quite similar again to Pinterest styling in that it left an uneven area at the base os stacked images.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late but this library does what you need:

http://masonjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

in my travels i have worked on a few responsive sites via css3 media queries. here is a modified solution i found and used in cases where i need to trigger javascript on the event of changes in the media queries:

```
// define a query here
var theQuery = "(min-width: 960px)";

var mql = window.matchMedia( theQuery );
var TO = setTimeout( function(){}, 100);

var handleMediaChange = function (mediaQueryList) {
    if (mediaQueryList.matches) {

        // the media query evaluates to true
        clearTimeout(TO);
        window.state = 0;

        TO = setTimeout( function(){
            // javascript actions go here   
        }, 100 );

    } else {

        // @media query evaluates to false
        clearTimeout(TO);
        window.state = 0;   

        TO = setTimeout( function(){
            // javascript actions go here   
        }, 100 );

    }
}

mql.addListener(handleMediaChange);
handleMediaChange(mql);
```

in essence it allows us to define a query and then add a listener to watch the window object for changes that would trigger our query.  when it triggers i have defined two sets of javascript one each for media query evaluating to true or false, but you could remove this if condition and just have any change execute some script...

give this a try and hope it helps